# Can gravitational effects from past matter that you're looking at lightyears away produce an incorrect image of it?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, dark-matter

Can gravitational effects from past matter that you're looking at lightyears away produce an incorrect image of it?

During the period that light from distant matter is travelling back to earth, can the original matter grow and evolve in such a way that it's mass is large enough to distort the light so we don't actually see a true representation of past matter?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137915/discussion-on-question-by-andersson09-is-it-possible-that-present-gravity-can-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because gravitational and electromagnetic waves travel at the same speed.

That means that changes in gravity that occur at the origin after the some electromagnetic waves departed can never catch up to affect them.

And since all matter also travels slower than electromagnetic waves, it means that the matter cannot catch up to the electromagnetic waves to produce gravitational effects in-situ and have them influence or accompany the electromagnetic waves which are already en route to the destination.

Look at this way: When looking an object, do you ever expect to simultaneously see the object at two different instances in time? Of course not, because that would imply that one of the images has time traveled (either into the object's own past or into its own future).

---

That said, it does not mean that EM waves traveling between a source and a destination cannot be affected by en route by the gravity of a third object where, when observed *at the destination*, the cumulative effect of the gravity on the electromagnetic waves does not match the gravity indicated by the image of the third *when observed at the destination upon arrival to the destination*. In fact, this is inevitable and is what happens for everything you observe to some degree.

That is because everything takes time. It takes time for for the gravitational effects of the third source to reach the electromagnetic waves en route, and it also takes time for the electromagnetic waves from the third source to reach the destination. Unless the third source was already at the destination, there is going to be a difference in the image you see of the third source and its gravitational effects of the light from the origin.

You probably won't see anything quite so drastic as an image being gravitationaly lensed by an object that is no longer there or drastically out of position when observed from the destination. Mainly because matters does not just blink out of existence and mass moves so slowly compared to the light so it can't move far enough relative to the image to look drastically different at the destination. The objects that can produce such gravity also tend to be so large that for them to be visibly moving relative to their size would require unreasonable speeds.

This type of thing actually happens *all the time* everywhere and not just over the vast distances of space. It happens all around you. When you have multiple free electric charges, they each contribute to the surrounding electric field. But they are also moved by the electric field, and when they move their contribution to the electric field changes but these changes can only propagate outwards at the speed of light. It's not instantaneous. Which means that when two free electric charges cause each other to move, they are being moved by the electric field produced by where the other charge *used to be*, not where it currently "is".

I put that in quotes because the whole thing about relativity comes up here. The image you see of me in your present is actually an image of me in my past.

Comment: This is all correct. But it may be worth noting that gravitational lensing by *other* matter between the source and the observer could result in radiation emitted by a single source at two different times T1 and T2 being superimposed and observed symultaneously by an observer at some later time T3.

Comment: @Penguino Indeed I was typing a section of that out. Tricky without a drawing though.

Comment: @Penguino To see if I understand what you're saying: so the other matter in between can keep growing in mass after its image has been recorded, affecting the light coming from source? Or are you saying something different?

Comment: @andersson09 Basically, if you were riding on the light en route, you would see a different image of the third object than what someone on Earth would see of the third object until you reached Earth. That means that gravity modifications performed by the third object to the light en route would be different that the what Earth would observe the gravity of the third object to be. When you finally reach the Earth, your observation and Earth's observation of the third object would match.

Comment: But the gravity has already intercepted and affected the light en route, and what the third object looked like to you (someone riding with the light) when that happened looked different than what the third object looks like when you arrive on Earth and turn around to look at the object. Therefore, the effects of gravity on the light do not match what the gravity observed from the image of the third object at the time you arrive on Earth.

Comment: @andersson09 No, firstly I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'growing in mass' - better to just say 'changing in distribution of mass'. Secondly,  a 2nd obj can affect the path of the light from a 1st obj in such a way that the  *apperent* history of the 1st objis altered to a viewer. But only by its influence on the light at/around the time the light passes 'near' the 2nd obj.  If that 2nd obj, for example collapsed into a black hole *after* it has distorted the light path from 1st obj, that event wontchange the light that has already gone past it.

Comment: @Penguino That's what I'm trying to say. But also that light received from the 2nd object may indicate an image that is not 100% true to what caused the gravitational lensing since after the 2nd has emitted light, light is still travelling from the 1st whilst the 2nd is accumulating more mass than originally seen and causes additional gravitational waves to distort the 1st object's radiation in which the image of the 2nd can't explain. Does this make sense?

Comment: @andersson09 Maybe you should stop trying to talk about things like "growing" or "accumulating" mass. because mass does not blink into existence. It has to travel in from elsewhere and that mass is always producing gravity of its own even as it does so. And you still seem to be talking as if gravity and light travel at different speeds in that last comment.

Comment: @DKNguyen Aren't galaxies formed by accumulating mass from clustering and merging? First stars become galaxies which can later form galaxy clusters right? In my last comment,  I guess it depends on how far away the 2nd object is from the 1st, i.e does the 2nd have enough time to form a galaxy before radiation from the 1st passes it. I would really appreciate it if you could create a drawing of some sort so I can see if it matches up to what's in my head.

Comment: @andersson09 Yes, but it's very ambiguous in this context because matter that is always producing gravity anyways slowly moving relative to the speed of light and over vast distances results in very small continuous changes that you can almost ignore. Unless matter can just blink in and out of existence which obviously isn't the case. It's difficult to know what you really have in mind because the former is inconsequential while the latter is wrong.

Comment: The differences we are talking about when a third object are involved have more to do with different time delay of causality between two observers than what you seem to have in mind.

Comment: @DKNguyen would you like to discuss in the chat that was created above? I'm worried mods wont like the lengthy comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137963/discussion-between-dknguyen-and-andersson09).